# Adding a Null Value to a Drop Down List

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

So I currently have a drop down list that pulls it's data directly from a database query.  It's a list of jobs for a jobs for a profile.  Now say, I want to add an option for "No Jobs" at the top of the drop down that sets a null value in the DB.  How would I go about doing that? I've tried hard coding an ArrayList in my controller and doing a call in a  tags to it, but that did not work. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<form:select path="job.jobName">



            <form:options items="${jobList}" itemValue="jobName" itemLabel="jobName" />

              </form:select>

             </td>

              <td><form:errors path="job.jobName" /> </td>



         </tr>

         </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add form:option as separate element. Below is the code.

```
<form:select path="job.jobName">
            <form:option value="">No Jobs</form:option> 
            <form:options items="${jobList}" itemValue="jobName" itemLabel="jobName" />
              </form:select>
             </td>
              <td><form:errors path="job.jobName" /> </td>
         </tr>
         </table>
```

Comment: I've tried that, but it will throw an error the way I have it setup that it isn't a value in the DB.

Comment: I found a small workaround, but it sort of bugs me. I have the item that declares that error.  I went into the controller commented out that code, and declared if the job name object is null to set it as null. So it works now... sort of.